# How to detect a product attribute with Javascript? (Magento)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

I have a working solution to a problem where we're replacing all 'Add to Cart' buttons with 'In Store Only' buttons for items that are only available in store. I'm using PHP to detect the attribute and produce HTML that replaces the button.

```
            <?php
            //Checks if the "Disable Add to Cart" variable is set to 'Yes': 
            if(($_product->getAttributeText('No_cart_button')) == "Yes"){
            //If set to Yes, tell PHP what to output:
            echo "This Product is not available online, please call our representative if you wish to purchase this.";
            }
            //If set as No, then show the 'add to cart box' as usual.
            else {
            ?>

            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
            <div class="add-to-box">
            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
            <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
            <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <div class="add-to-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

I've been told that Javascript would be a less intrusive way of doing achieving the same result. Am I right in assuming that you would use PHP to insert a class or id into the HTML element and do the rest with Javascript? Detect the id or class --> generate the replacement button?

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using PHP for this, actually I think it's better than javascript because not everyone has javascript enabled plus you'd see a small delay after the page loads and before the button is replaced

Comment: That was my thinking as well! Our page load times aren't exactly lightning fast. I could see it hiccuping and allowing someone to check out with the product.